# How to get Yelp to open the docs?

Tags: application-development, quickly, documentation, file-association, yelp

[image]
`quickly tutorial`
[image]
Result: An empty Yelp window with the XML file opened in gedit.

`yelp /usr/share/quickly/templates/ubuntu-application/help/tutorial.xml` --> Exactly the same problem.

Worked fine a few days ago.

Manually changing the file association of XML files to Yelp (which I actually don't want to do, because all other XML files should open in gedit), and then running the command again gets my system into an infinite loop.

Comment: This unanswered question is 5+ years old and must be Ubuntu 12.04 which is EOL or an even older EOL version. If in future someone else has similar problems with `yelp` they can post a new question. VTC as `not reproducible`.